# Python : where clause with group by clause in sqlite

Tags: python-2.7, sqlite

I am using `python 2.7` with `sqlite`.
Can anyone tell me how to add `GROUP BY coulmn` in this query.

```
cur.execute("SELECT `column1`,`column2` FROM `table` WHERE `name`=?",(name,))
```

Comment: Can someone tell me what is wrong in this question?Why this question 3 down voted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cur.execute("SELECT `column1`,`column2` FROM `table`  WHERE `name`=? GROUP BY `column`",(name,) )
```